# Are there naturalization records specific to displaced ethnic Jews?

Tags: united-states, jewish, naturalization

From WW1-WW2, are there a set of records for Jews separate from other naturalization records in the U.S? If so, where can they be accessed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a direct answer, but can possibly suggest a couple of places to look.  In his book *In Search of Your German Roots* (4th Ed., 2008), Angus Baxter writes "In all of my previous books I have included a separate section on Jewish records and this book is no exception...The most dramatic development in Jewish record-keeping in North America in recent years has been the creation of the Center for Jewish History":

```
Center for Jewish History
15 West 16th St.
New York, NY 10011
212-294-8301
www.cjh.org
```

He also lists:

```
American Jewish Archives
3101 Clifton Ave.
Cincinnati, OH  45220
513-221-1875
www.americanjewisharchives.org

American Jewish Historical Society
160 Herrick Rd.
Newton Centre, MA  02459
617-559-8880
www.ajhs.org
```

I've not had reason to utilize any of these organizations, nor even visit their websites, so I can't say to what extent they might help address your question.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start with doing research in this area of interest is [JewishGen.org](http://www.jewishgen.org/). They do have an entry on [Naturalization records](http://www.jewishgen.org/InfoFiles/faq.html#Naturalization) in their Frequently Asked Questions.

Consider, however, that any subset of Naturalization records, or any records, that someone might select from a larger database because the people in the records are perceived to be Jewish will be prone to error -- there are bound to be people included who are not ethnically Jewish because someone thought their name sounded like they might be, and there might be people who are missing because the people making the extract didn't think people with that surname belonged in the database.  (This is one of the criticisms of the *Germans to America* volumes of passenger lists.)

I don't know of any, but even if there were such a specialized record collection, you might be better off searching in the full dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the interwar period, the 1920's and early 1930's?  If so, I am not aware of any Jewish-specific settlement, immigration, or naturalization policies within the US at that time, so I am not sure how they could have created separate records.  Indeed, there was a distinctly anti-immigration movement in place in those years, and policies becomes even more restrictive.

There *were* some records specific to visas-for-Jews during and immediately after WWII, though, as displaced persons.

But as always, JewishGen is your best bet to ask about this, though.  Their mailing lists are free and very informative.